# Heat Resistant Wire Insulation Types

Tags: wire, insulation

Good afternoon all,

For the past several months I have been working on a project at work and the wire I am using is amazing.  When I go to solder it into a joint, the insulation does not shrink and run up the wire.  I LOVE this wire.

Several of the wire rolls that I am using are quickly becoming empty and I need to replace the wire.  So, I go to my friendly neighborhood electronics supplier and start looking at all the wire. I get what I thought would be the perfect replacement.  I succeeded in getting a heat-resistant insulation, but I failed in getting a nickle plated copper wire.  I cannot solder this stuff for nothing.

So, I am back to needing wire and wondering what to order.  Can someone provide some guidance at least on what insulation to choose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've asked us to identify what you want without showing us what you have. Silicone?

Comment: Teflon or Silicone are heat resistant. It is easier to find cheap Silicone wire. What gauge? Solid or Stranded?

Answer (score 1):

It's Teflon insulated silver-plated copper wire.

Comment: A tin plated copper wire will do too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be teflon, cross-linked PVC, or silicone insulation.

Regular PVC or polyetheylene  insulation melts easily.  but wires intended for soldering resist melting.

a silver coloured surface is probably silver or tin.

Answer (score 0):

Teflon (PTFE) insulation is generally relatively thin and feels waxy.

Silicone insulation is rubbery and can be stripped with fingernails. It tends to be thicker.

There are other insulation systems that don’t easily melt back, like Kynar (PVDF) and Kapton (Polyimide).

There are other reasons to use wire insulation that is capable of high temperature operation than high temperature- such as chemical resistance, low outgassing, thinner insulation etc.

Nickel plating is intended for high temperature operation and is generally crimped into lugs etc. Silver plating is also used for high temperature operation but is solderable when not corroded.